# Convert "2018-02-02T06:54:57.744Z" String to date in Android

Tags: java, android, iso8601

Basically my date string is ISO-8601 date string, So I searched for converting ISO-8601 date string to date, but the solutions are lengthy. Here are the details.

I have a string `2018-02-02T06:54:57.744Z` want to convert it to Date but I am getting error:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2018-02-02T06:54:57.744Z"
```

I am using following technique to do that but no success:

```
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX");
        parser.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        Date parsed = parser.parse(utcDateString);
        return parsed;
```

I also use following patterns with `SimpleDateFormat` but no success:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'
```

any solution to this problem.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`Z` is timezone. You have to add timezone at the end of your date string or simply remove it from format: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss`

A correct date string with timezone is something like this: `2018-02-02T06:54:57.744+0200`

Comment: Thanks using only yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss in pattern solve the problem.

Answer (score 16):

Try this

```
SimpleDateFormat input = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

Date d = null;
try 
{
   d = input.parse("2018-02-02T06:54:57.744Z");
} 
catch (ParseException e) 
{
   e.printStackTrace();
}
String formatted = output.format(d);
Log.i("DATE", "" + formatted);
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Thanks adding this line input.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")); give me correct result.

Comment: @Zulqarnain Thanks, Happy to help you.

Comment: Sir thanks for helping me out but Ali Behzadian Nejad answer first and just replacing the pattern to this  yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss  give me correct result. your answer was more in detail and correct as well I appreciate your time.

Comment: @Zulqarnain Thanks as you wish.

Answer (score 8):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.parse( “2018-02-02T06:54:57.744Z” )
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses java.time classes.

`Instant` is the replacement for `java.util.Date`, representing a moment on the timeline in UTC.

Your input string happens to comply with the ISO 8601 standard. The java.time classes use standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( “2018-02-02T06:54:57.744Z” ) ;
```

Best to avoid the troublesome `java.util.Date` class entirely. But if you insist, convert using new methods added to the old classes.

```
Date d = Date.from( instant ) ;
```

For earlier Android, see the *ThreeTen-Backport* and *ThreeTenABP* projects.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).